# Showing Two elements from XML file

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

The file can be seen on the following URL: #

The above XML file consists of two elements which I want to be shown in order which are the "product" and "offer".

I use SimpleXML to load the XML feed.

> $text = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');

I also use foreach to show the data from the file

```
foreach ($text->categories->category->items->product as $product) {}
```

How is it possible to show the "product" and "offer" from the XML file using a for each statement or any other method?

Comment: You are saying that you "show the data from the file". So what do you mean "How is it possible to show the "product"" if you already show them?

Comment: By that I mean how can I show both pieces of data, instead of showing just one? I have come across XPath however not sure if it can be used in this case.

Comment: XPath makes reading XML data very easy. But explain exactly how you want to display your data, because now it's not clear how `product` items relate `offer`.

Comment: The product and offer consist of different pieces of information about products returned in the XML file. Currently I am currently only able to show products or offer, where I want to display them both in any order. For example display the amount of products and offers from the feed in order.

Comment: Currently I display the data from the product element via  'print $text->categories->category->items->product->name;' and via the offer element I would use 'print $text->categories->category->items->product->offers->offer->name;' However I only can use product or offer so that's why I want to use XPath to show them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `<items>` only ever contain `<product>` and `<offer>` elements? If so:

```
foreach ($text->categories->category->items->children() as $product_or_offer) {
    // Do something
}
```

See http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children

---

If you want to be explicit about only ever getting the product/offer elements, a simple XPath expression could be employed.

```
$items = $text->categories->category->items;
$items->registerXPathNamespace('so', 'urn:types.partner.api.url.com');
foreach ($items->xpath('so:offer|so:product') as $product_or_offer) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Both of the product and offer elements contain near the same elements however, how would it be possible to for example only show "totalPrice" for the offer only and something else for the product?

Comment: Sure. You can use `$product_or_offer->getName()` to see which one you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm still don't really get what you would like to obtain I will post some examples of how to deal with this XML via xPath.

First of all select all `product` and `offer` nodes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');

// Make sure to register custom namespace
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'urn:types.partner.api.url.com');

$products = $xml->xpath('//ns:product');
$offers   = $xml->xpath('//ns:offer');

echo count($products); // Number of all product nodes
echo count($offers); // Number of offer nodes
```

Basic iteration:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($product); echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'; echo $product->name . ', ' . $product->minPrice; echo '</pre>';
}
```